# How to solve this inequality？

Tags: inequalities

This inequality:

```
-1 + a E^x > 0
```

```
In[6]:= Reduce[-1 + a E^x > 0, x]

During evaluation of In[6]:= Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

Out[6]= Reduce[-1 + a E^x > 0, x]
```

Comment: Can you, please, provide a question formatted properly so that others can read and understand? Do keep in mind, that questions and answers on this site are meant to be of use and help to the many! Many thanks

Comment: `Reduce[-1 + a E^x > 0, x, Reals]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ineq1 = -1 + a E^x > 0 /. E^x -> y


(*  -1 + a y > 0  *)
```

Then:

```
Simplify[
 Map[Evaluate[Log[#]] &, Reduce[ineq1 && a > 0, y][[2]] /. y -> E^x], 
 x \[Element] Reals]

(* x > Log[1/a]  *)
```

Have fun!